# PHP mail() doesn't send e-mail

Tags: php, email, error-handling

I have a question for all you out there.

I've noticed that my php mail isn't sent anymore. So I looked into it to determine what the problem is but I can't seem to find it.

This is the case:

In powershell 3 (server 2012)I use the following command:

```
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.versatel.nl
```

and after giving the to e-mail address, a subject and a from address it sends the mail without any problem.

The code in the PHP file is:

```
INI_SET("SMTP", "smtp.versatel.nl");
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

preg_match("/\d+/", $error["message"], $error);
if(!$success){$this->sFoutmelding ='Email is niet verstuurd.'.print_r($error);}
```

In the php.ini I disabled the default ini settings:

```
mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; SMTP = Smtp.versatel.nl
; smtp_port = 25
```

But still I get an error that the mail isn't sent:

```
Array ( )
Email is niet verstuurd.1
```

Why doesn't php send the mail when powershell does this perfectly?
Any ideas are welcome, I have searched on and off the whole week over the internet, but i can't find an answer.

*edit

I tried the var_dump and it gives, as expected, only a 'FALSE'.

Also the change in 'localhost' didn't do the trick. Still searching...

Comment: put a `var_dump` on your `mail` function to find out what it returns (true/false) - we're going to assume here that it's returning false, but might be nice to make sure.

Comment: This is not the specific solution for your problem but i recommend you to use a established mail-library like swiftmailer or PHPMailer. Some Providers refuse Mails because of wrong headers and other things. You don't wanna handle all those issues!

Comment: Since your computer can connect to the remote server, it must be getting back a specific error message - try tapping the connection with wireshark if it's not visible in error reporting. After you've identified the error speak to your SMTP provider.

Comment: I'd check the mail server logs to see if they recorded a connect attempt. I don't know PHP so this may be a dumb question, but it looks like you've disabled the default server and port settings, but only provided a new value for the server.  Does it need that port setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working, but still no explonation why :-) So if someone knows why, I like to know it too :-)

It still uses the same smtp server as without the phpmailer class. So the only thing I can think off is the fact that PHPmailer creates a different, more widly excepted, mail header than the default one of PHP.

I added the following code and class PHP mailer:

```
$success = $this->mail_attachment($to, $subject, $body);

protected function mail_attachment($mailto, $subject, $message) {
require_once("../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
//$file = $path.$filename;
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.versatel.nl"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "noreply@provider.foo";
$mail->FromName = "Sendername";
$mail->AddAddress($mailto);


$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 75;
//$mail->AddAttachment($file);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Bevestigings e-mail is niet verzonden.';
      echo 'Mailer error is: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```